# Installing multiple npm versions

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Is it possible to install multiple versions of `npm` for different projects that I am working on or are the `npm` installations always global? (Windows 10)

Are also tried installing different versions with https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist but it seems to affect only the node version, not the npm version.

Or does npm version actually matter? Can I just use the newest npm version even when a project says the requirement is a certain npm version?

Comment: Re: last paragraph. Yes, the npm version may matter. There are big differences between npm `2.x` and `3.x`, e.g. in version 3 packages are deduped by default, which may affect some apps that expect some dependency file at a specific path in `node_modules`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can install multiple versions of `npm` by installing multiple versions of `node`. To do this, you can use [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). Each different installation of `node` installs a different version of `npm`

To use a different version of `node` and `nvm` in a project, you simple need to switch:

```
nvm use 5.0
```

You can also create a `.nvmrc` file containing the version number in the project root directory. `nvm` will use the specified version of `node` for that project.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `.nvmrc` files.  I've been switching back and forth using `nvm` when projects require different versions and this is a huge timesaver.

Comment: @gnerkus I am using nvm but looking for npm 4.6.1 this is recommended for react native it does not seem like any of the nodes come with this version is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Say you have 2 projects using Node 10.18.0 (having "10.18.0" in their respective `.nvmrc` file). How would you set it up so that when working on project 1 it uses npm 7.5.0 and when using project 2 it uses npm 6.13.4 ?

Comment: I just recently ran into this issue when running `npm install`  (old npm version of 6.x with node 16.14.0) when using nvm. I was expecting that using `nvm use 16.14.0` will solve my issue (`npm npm does not support Node.js v16.14.0`). In VSC on Windows it threw the error, but when running `npm intsall` as administrator (in Cmder) it suprisingly installed everything without throwing the error. Any ideas as of why nvm (which requires admin rights) might affect this?

Answer (score 7):

You also can install `npm` using `npm`

Example of installing specific version:

`npm i -g npm@3.5.4`

Comment: You cant downgrade version of npm easily.

Comment: @dorgan, can you provide an example, please? I have not had problems downgrading npm myself.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use a different version of npm for each project, there are a number of possible solutions. Probably the lightest-weight version is to use `npx`. A semi-common use-case for this can be projects that use lock-file v1 and another that uses lock-file v2. v2 was introduced in npm v7.

So in your project using lockfile v1, if you need to install a new package.

```bash
npx npm@v6 install dalle-node
```

For lockfile v2, or to just use the latest and great.

```bash
npx npm@latest install dalle-node
```

> Or does npm version actually matter?

In most cases, it's not likely to matter much. The above example is one I run in to in my own projects. If you use a project and some of the npm commands are giving you trouble, e.g. `npm run`, try using the version of npm the project recommends before filing a bug with the maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using eclipse IDE for Node projects, you can easily change Node version using [Webclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/webclipse) plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't look to install multiple versions of `npm` to manage same node packages, instead you should look to manage multiple versions of `nodejs`, each `nodejs` with bring its own minimum version of `npm` required with it and that's how you will get multiple versions of `npm` with multiple versions of `nodejs`. When you switch `node` version, the `npm` versions will switch automatically.
To manage multiple versions of `nodejs` you can use `nvm` or `n`

```
nvm install <nodejs version>
nvm use <nodejs version>
```

What Thiago Caiubi mentions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35202877/865220) is upgrading `npm` version within a given `nodejs` version . That update will happen only for that `nodejs` version . The corresponding `npm` for each of the other `nodejs` versions will not be touched.