# Having 2 npm versions at the same time

Tags: npm

How to have 2 versions of npm at the same time? Im saying like I can do `python` and `python3`, can I run something like `npm4` and `npm5`? I need to use npm 4 for a create-react-native-app project but I need npm 5 to be there for other projects. Thanks in advance :-).

EDIT: Basically I want to know how to switch between npm versions if `npm4 npm5` is not there. Like maybe `npm switch-version(??) 4`.

EDIT 2: I saw some other question like this but that uses NVM. I do not want anything new for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing multiple npm versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201722/installing-multiple-npm-versions)

Comment: That uses NVM. I am asking without anything else. Will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download the distribution packages yourself (https://nodejs.org/dist/) in different versions und create simple bash script in a directory which is part of your `PATH` with a call to npm for each version.

Comment: But does npm provide functionality itself? Or do I *have* to do something manually?

Comment: No, npm does not have the ability to provide different versions. If u need different versions, try NVM as recommended above. Also, did you mean to switch between different NodeJS or npm versions? You should be able to use the latest npm version to do everything you need to do. Bear in mind, that never npm versions might not be compatible with older NodeJS versions.

Comment: Alright thanks! I will try nvm. I needed npm 4 for a create-react-native-app project because it does not support npm 5.